# Adding 3rd party modules to Materializecss?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I want to add tooltip-balloon (https://github.com/goisneto/Tooltip-Balloon) into my  node_modules for materializecss and am unsure what the best method is to do that with NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM is able to [install packages from Git repositories](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) even if they weren't published in NPM repository, but Git repository should contain `package.json` in order to be installed.

Since [github.com/goisneto/Tooltip-Balloon](https://github.com/goisneto/Tooltip-Balloon) doesn't contain `package.json`, a fork and/or pull request should be created to add it to the repository.

An alternative is to use other package manager that supports non-NPM packages like [`napa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/napa).